# Getting new collections in mongodb is not working in mongodb c# driver

Tags: c#, mongodb

Consider This code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient();
    var mongoServer = mongo.GetServer();
    mongoServer.Connect();
    var db = mongoServer.GetDatabase("Shelf", WriteConcern.Unacknowledged);

    mongoServer.RequestStart(db);
    db.GetCollection("Book" + 1).Insert(new BsonDocument
                          {
                              {"_id", ObjectId.GenerateNewId(DateTime.Now)},
                              {
                                  "Properties", new BsonDocument
                                                {
                                                    {"title", "qwd"},
                                                    {"author", "a good writer1"},
                                                }
                              },
                              {"ISBN", "23423525"},
                          });

    db.GetCollection("Book" + 2).Insert(new BsonDocument
                          {
                              {"_id", ObjectId.GenerateNewId(DateTime.Now)},
                              {
                                  "Properties", new BsonDocument
                                                {
                                                    {"title", "qwdqw"},
                                                    {"author", "a good writer2"},
                                                }
                              },
                              {"ISBN", "23423525"},
                          });

    mongoServer.RequestDone();
}
```

I'm using MongoDb C# driver in my program. After running the above code for the first time, I get only `Book1` created in `Shelf` Db and not the other one collection though there is no exception raising during the execution. With further executions of this code other collection is also created. Why MongoDb C# driver is behaving like this and what is wrong with my code? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is with  `WriteConcern.Unacknowledged`.You should change it to `WriteConcern.Acknowledged`.You are not waiting until the writing requests are sent to mongod.
You may check journal option for this matter too.